# How to choose a specific date (when: type = "date") in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, date, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver with Java, and I'm trying to pick a date in the Date of Birth field on this site:
http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/addcustomerpage.php

How can I choose a specific date on this site via Selenium WebDriver?

I tried to use this command (using Firefox driver):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dob")).sendKeys("04/11/2013");
```

But this command does not work.

I expect the date will appear: 04/11/2013,
But the date does not change (mm/dd/yyyy).

Comment: What do you mean by `this command does not work?`, do you get any error?

Comment: I mean the date does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a valid Date format like yyyy-mm-dd

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dob")).sendKeys("2013-04-11");
```

This will work in Firefox as well

Comment: @Adi Ohana Any idea why we have to send the date in different format for firefox?

Comment: @mick this post will explain the issue: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1070

Answer (score 0):

I see the date changes to "04/11/2013" with the same code you used.

[image]
If you are trying to change the date then make sure to clear the field first using below line

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dob")).clear();
```

Comment: The code works in Chrome but does not work in Firefox (I try to make the date change in Firefox)

Comment: I tried to use the code:
driver.findElement(By.id ("dob")).clear();
But still the date does not change...